# javamail InternetAddress RFC822 Format

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, rfc822

I am validating a email address adheres to the RFC822 format by a creating email address object using javamail 1.4.4 'InternetAddress' Class.

```
InternetAddress internetAdd = new InternetAddress("test@test.com");
```

If it throws an AddressException then it's invalid.

Is there any simpler break down of what type of email address are accepted other than reading the RFC822 documentation?
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc822/#z25

For example, what special charchters can it contain, etc?

Thanks

Comment: Verifying EMail addresses is really, really tough. [This Q/A might help.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/624581/what-is-the-best-java-email-address-validation-method)

Comment: Thanks Andreas. Yeah I think we will stick with the use of InternetAddress and use the following link as a reference for what is acceptable in the local part: http://www.remote.org/jochen/mail/info/chars.html. Basically, we will need to agree upon what is acceptable and not between development and QA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with the javamail InternetAddress method in the end. There are common things that you would think it should reject, but are actually acceptable!