# Email validation in java

Tags: java, email-validation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best Java email address validation method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624581/what-is-the-best-java-email-address-validation-method)

I need to know if there is any method in java to implement email validation for addresses like

**xyz@yahoo.com,xyz@yahoo.co.in**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this code.

```
static Pattern emailPattern = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9[!#$%&'()*+,/\\-_\\.\"]]+@[a-zA-Z0-9[!#$%&'()*+,/\\-_\"]]+\\.[a-zA-Z0-9[!#$%&'()*+,/\\-_\"\\.]]+");
public static boolean isValidEmail(String email) 
{       
    Matcher m = emailPattern.matcher(email);
        return !m.matches();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`org.apache.commons.validator.EmailValidator`](http://commons.apache.org/validator/api-1.3.1/org/apache/commons/validator/EmailValidator.html) which is part of [Apache Commons Validator](http://commons.apache.org/validator/).

Or use a Jsr-303 validation framework (e.g. [Hibernate Validator](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/validator.html)) which offers a `@Email` validator.

Comment: EmailValidator also gives you the option of excluding local email addresses so that the top level domain must be present, which was a requirement for me.