# Email Validation RFC 2821 using Java

Tags: email-validation, jakarta-mail, rfc822, rfc2822

I am working on email Validation using java having RFC 2821 in mind.
I have used following code to validate all my email address:

```
InternetAddress emailAddr = new InternetAddress(email);
emailAddr.validate();
```

Java api says its RFC-822 compliant. Is there a much difference between RFC 2821 and 822?

Also the above api is failing to validate email in below cases:

1. `var@yahoo` - validation returns true, but it is invalid email
2. `var(comment)@yahoo.com` - validation returns false, but it is valid email

Can you tell me any work around for this to get it done.

Comment: Are you sure `ar@yahoo` should be invalid? I would check if a generic top-level domain can be used as a host name.

Comment: And the documentation says: "Validate the address portion" so I guess that everything after the `@` is ignored.

Comment: In a previous question Apache Commons was suggested as the best tool (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/624581/what-is-the-best-java-email-address-validation-method) but I just tried and it also fails to accept comments.

Answer (score 1):

There are major differences between how modern e-mail addresses are handled vs the e-mail addresses in the original standards.

From what I've experienced setting up dns & bind addresses you can specify a domain name without a period, but when the resolver is queried it will add the `.` to the end of the domain name. You can also specify a straight mapping in a hosts file. Most hosts files contain resolve localhost like this:

> 127.0.0.1  localhost loopback

Meaning if you're on the server with the mail server you can send a valid e-mail to `user@localhost`.

According to [RFC 822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822#section-6.2.1):

> In the case of formal registration, an organization implements a
> (distributed)  data base which provides an address-to-route mapping
> service for addresses of the form:
>
> ```
>             person@registry.organization
> ```
>
> Note that "organization" is a logical  entity,  separate  from any
> particular communication network.
>
> A mechanism for accessing "organization" is universally avail- able.
> That mechanism, in turn, seeks an instantiation of the registry; its
> location is not indicated in the address specif- ication.   It  is
> assumed that the system which operates under the name "organization"
> knows how to find a subordinate regis- try.  The registry will then
> use the "person" string to deter- mine where to send the mail
> specification.
>
> The latter,  network-oriented  case  permits  simple,  direct,
> attachment-related address specification, such as:
>
> ```
>                  user@host.network
> ```

In the case of `user@host.network` on local systems as long as the email system is configured properly you can send emails to `user@host`. Even though this isn't the [FQDN - Fully Qualified Domain Name](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4703) that we're used to now, that standard didn't come around until much later. The mail system then uses the alias to send it to the correct local network translating the email to `user@host.network`. The problems with e-mail spoofing didn't come around until later when the ARPAnet became public.

About the comments in the address, that was not in RFC 822. According to the later email specification which allows comments ([RFC 2822 Section 3.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.4)):

> Also, because some legacy implementations interpret    the comment,
> comments generally SHOULD NOT be used in address fields    to avoid
> confusing such implementations.

Meaning older systems do not allow comments in addresses. [RFC 822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822#section-6.1) does not mention comments in the e-mail address.

The technical fix would be to not allow comments in the e-mail address unless you're accommodating them with custom code. You could always update Javamail. [Newer implementations accommodate updated RFCs.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me that you want to validate email ids that are used nowadays and not really to be compliant to any RFC.
For our project we made our own very simple email validator. Why ? The apache and java mail one use regex and there are some cases (I do not know which as we were not printing the email's in the log) that make regex go in to a forever loop. This means the client handler thread goes into a loop and the user sees a blank screen!

So what we do is essentially allow new email ids like they would look like at sites like google/ yahoo.

Meaning somecahrs@xyz.com

What we check for
At most 1 @
Check for 1 or more chars before @
After @ have some chars + one dot atleast  + chrs after dot

Did not get any complaints for the last two years. Also most of the times you need to send the person an email to make sure the domain exists etc and a link with a unique token (sign up confirm) to make sure the person owns the email id (with a message to real owner to only click if they came to your site)

```
    /**
     * minimum email l@n.co
     * */
    public static boolean checkEmail(final String emlId, int dbgPrint) {
        // ex:ak@bv.gh
        if (emlId == null){
            return false;
        }
        final int lngth = emlId.length();
        if (lngth < 6) {
            if (dbgPrint > 1) {
                System.out.println(" lngth < 6");
            }
            return false;
        }
        final int locationAt = emlId.indexOf('@');
        if (locationAt < 1) {
            if (dbgPrint > 1) {
                System.out.println("locationAt < 1 : " + locationAt);
            }
            return false;//
        }
        final int postLastPeriod = emlId.lastIndexOf('.');
        if (postLastPeriod < 0) {
            if (dbgPrint > 1) {
                System.out.println("postLastPeriod < 0, locationAt " + locationAt);
            }
            return false;
        }
        if (dbgPrint > 1) {
            System.out.println(" locationAt " + locationAt + ", postLastPeriod :" + postLastPeriod + " lngth " + lngth);
        }
        if (lngth - postLastPeriod < 3) {
            if (dbgPrint > 1) {
                System.out.println(" lngth - postLastPeriod < 2");
            }
            return false;
        }
        if (postLastPeriod - locationAt < 1) {
            if (dbgPrint > 1) {
                System.out.println(" postLastPeriod - locationAt < 1");
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    }
```