# Library for email searching

Tags: java, regex, email, text-processing

I need to find email addresses in a block of plain text. Regexps regularly hang. Is there some java library that can locate emails in text string?

From a later comment: I need to find email in a string to replace it w. hyperlink.

Comment: you are talking about your own emails right? in times of PRISM I just had to ask...

Comment: You are searching text data which happens to be an email. How is this text data formatted or stored? Do you have it in a flat file? In a database?

Comment: Do you mean finding valid email addresses in plain text or search email text for some string?

Comment: Are you sure it's the regex handling that is resource-greedy (sorry for the unintended pun here)? You could probably improve performance by using a constant Pattern (see also Anirudh's answer for a Pattern example) and only one instance of Matcher that iterates over the find() method until text is parsed. If your corpus is very large, you could use a buffered reader and reinitialize your Matcher every line... Need to see some code here.

Comment: I identify emails to make href.

Comment: Can you share a sample input and what you want the output to look like?

Answer (score 2):

An email address is valid if you can send a message to it

Use `\S+@\S+`(**warning**: even space is valid) regex to search for emails.

Then you should send a message to that email and wait for response from the user.

If email address is valid you would receive a **response**,if not then you can assume that the email address is **invalid**.This is the only correct way to validate an email address.

---

have a look at

- [What is the best Java email address validation method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624581/what-is-the-best-java-email-address-validation-method)
- [Simple Explanation of E-mail address format (RFC 822)](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/rfc/822addr.html)
- [Email Address format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address)
- [RFC 822 Standard](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc822.txt)

Comment: +1 for this answer, but it doesn't really address the OP's question.

Comment: Yes, this in not an answer.

Comment: @stiv the first [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/624581/what-is-the-best-java-email-address-validation-method) in the ans answers your question!

Comment: No, it doesn't. I need to _find_ email in a string to replace it w. hyperlink.