# Simple Email Validation for Java Program

Tags: java

I was looking for a very simple email validation.  It just have to have an @ symbol and a period in the email.  I want to accept for my string that will come in as a parameter.

Does anyone know of any easy email validations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is using [InternetAddress](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/InternetAddress.html) from JavaMail. Just do `new InternetAddress(email).validate()` and it will throw an `AddressException` if it's invalid.

Comment: It's not easy for me to test right now, but has the behavior changed since http://stackoverflow.com/a/5931718/616460 where it would (according to the comments there, which may be incorrect?) accept e.g. "abc" as a valid email?

Comment: It actually is a bit permissive. For instance, the email `root@localhost` would be a valid email address. You might want to add domain name filters in production, though.