# RFC 822 email address validation in java

Tags: java, validation, email-address

how is possible in Java validate email address by RFC 822? 
Are there any available official regular expression for full support RFC822? 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Very much related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address

Comment: Although the OP did mention regular expressions, the primary question is how to validate an email address. More appropriate would probably be: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/624581/what-is-the-best-java-email-address-validation-method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure is. Although this might be overkill. [Mail RFC822 Address.](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)