# How to check if an email address is valid?

Tags: java

Following is the code i am using:

Its always giving me output "Invalid email address"

```
BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String name="";
do
{
    System.out.println("Email:");
    String email= br.readLine();
    if(!name.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+(.[a-zA-Z]{2,})$"))
    System.out.println("Invalid email address");
    else
        break;  
}while(true);
```

Comment: You are getting email in email and matching name in if condition.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best Java email address validation method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/624581/what-is-the-best-java-email-address-validation-method)

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively you can use [apache validator](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/)

```
String email; //set the String...
System.out.println(EmailValidator.getInstance().isValid(email));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if(!name.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+(.[a-zA-Z]{2,})$"))
```

should be

```
if(!email.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+(.[a-zA-Z]{2,})$"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you should call

```
email.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+(.[a-zA-Z]{2,})$")
```

since name is constantly set to an empty string.