# JS regex to Java, syntax issues

Tags: javascript, java, regex

I have this to big regex that I use in JavaScript to validate email address.

```
/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
```

When I try to used them in Java, I get syntax errors.

> Unclosed character class near index 154 /^(([^<>()[]\.,;:\s@\"]+(.[^<>()[]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z-0-9]+.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/ ^

I'm using http://www.regexplanet.com/ to test the regex.

Is there any way to convert or escape chars or something like this? Thanks!

Comment: you do know it's very hard to get a regex to validate an email (as per RFC 822), right? http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html. See discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address

Comment: Tried using `input type="email"` ?

Comment: @guest271314 Still need server-side validation.

Comment: @DaveNewton If not valid client side , do not send to server ?

Comment: http://html5pattern.com/Emails

Comment: @guest271314 If a web form was the only way someone could send data to the server, sure. But it isn't, and believing it is leaves you *wide* open to the most *trivial* of hacks.

Comment: @DaveNewton Solution ?

Comment: @guest271314 Use both client-side validation (for immediate, high-level feedback) *and* server-side validation to protect your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the JS regex as a Java string literal:

```
"(([^<>()\\[\\].,;:\\s@\"]+(\\.[^<>()\\[\\].,;:\\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\\[[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\])|(([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))"
```

The anchors (`^$`) have been removed, since they're not needed when calling `matches()`.

All `\`, except `\"`, have been doubled.

`[` inside a class (`[]`) needed escaping, so escape added (`\\[`).

`.` inside a class (`[]`) don't need escaping, so escape removed.

`-` inside a class (`[]`) don't need escaping if placed last, so moved to end.

Answer (score 1):

I scaped some characters, the result is this:

```
/^
    (
        (
            [^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+
            (\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*
        )
        |
        (
            \".+\"
        )
    )

    @

    (
        (\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])
        |
        (([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,})
    )

$/
```

[regexplanet.com:link](http://www.regexplanet.com/cookbook/ahJzfnJlZ2V4cGxhbmV0LWhyZHNyDwsSBlJlY2lwZRjdneEaDA/index.html)

Seems like the problem was that there are some `[` unescaped.

Anyway I encorage you to see this question: [What-is-the-best-java-email-address-validation-method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624581/what-is-the-best-java-email-address-validation-method)

Answer (score 0):

I share with all the final regex [Java email address regex validator](http://regexper.com/#%2F%5E((%5B%5E%3C%3E()%5B%5C%5D%5C%5C.%2C%3B%3A%5Cs%40%5C%22%5D%2B(%5C.%5B%5E%3C%3E()%5B%5C%5D%5C%5C.%2C%3B%3A%5Cs%40%5C%22%5D%2B)*)%7C(%5C%22.%2B%5C%22))%40((%5C%5B%5B0-9%5D%7B1%2C3%7D%5C.%5B0-9%5D%7B1%2C3%7D%5C.%5B0-9%5D%7B1%2C3%7D%5C.%5B0-9%5D%7B1%2C3%7D%5C%5D)%7C((%5Ba-zA-Z%5C-0-9%5D%2B%5C.)%2B%5Ba-zA-Z%5D%7B2%2C%7D))%24%2F)