# Using Regex Formatter To Verify Email

Tags: regex, email, formatter

This is my code but it doesn't work,why?I use the RegexFormatter("*@*.*") but it seems doesn't work.it can't check the JFormattedTextField whether *@*.* contain or not.And I want to show the result at the verify label how should I do?

```
public class hw5 extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
private JPasswordField passwordField;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            try {
                hw5 frame = new hw5();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
public hw5() {
    setTitle("hw5");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JFormattedTextField FormattedField = new JFormattedTextField(new RegexFormatter("*@*.*"));
}

    }
class RegexFormatter extends DefaultFormatter {
  private Pattern pattern;

  private Matcher matcher;

  public RegexFormatter() {
    super();
  }

public Object stringToValue(String text) throws ParseException {
Pattern pattern = getPattern();

if (pattern != null) {
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

  if (matcher.matches()) {
    setMatcher(matcher);
    return super.stringToValue(text);
  }
  throw new ParseException("Pattern did not match", 0);
}
return text;
```

}
  }

Comment: Please do not simply post your half-done homework and hope that someone fixes it for you. At least, tell us what the result of your attempts are, and what else you have tried.

Comment: You could just do `text.contains("@");` :P

Answer (score 0):

Your regex `*@*.*` if wrong. It means:

- One `*`
- Followed by zero or more `@`
- Followed by zero or more characters (any)

Validating an e-mail via regex is [very complicated](http://emailregex.com) (if you want to do it correctly). Since it seems all you want to do is check for *"something with an `@`"*, I'd suggest the following regex:

```
[^@]+@[^@]+
```

Or better yet:

```
^[^@]+@.[^@]+$
```

It means:

- `^`: start of string
- `[^@]+`: followed by one or more characters that are not `@`
- `@`: a single `@`
- `[^@]+`: followed by one or more characters that are not `@`
- `$`

This will match `a@b` and `alpha+beta$@^&` but will fail on `foo` or `a@b@c`. Whether this is sufficient for you, I don't know. There are [far better ways to validate whether an input is an e-mail address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624581/what-is-the-best-java-email-address-validation-method).