# invalid email address string check (for school)

Tags: java, contains

I'm working on a project in school and I need to verify 5 email address from an arraylist.

I have to verify that all emails have '@' and '.' and don't have a space. Right now I'm just trying to get first part down.

This is what I have so far and when it calls it pulls all 5 email addresses. It seems like the contains would check for the chars and only return false on the emails that don't have it. I'm not looking for word for word answer. Just a bit of direction.

```
public static void print_invalid_emails()
{
    for (Student s : myRoster )
    {
        if(s.getEmailAddress().contains("@.") == false)
            System.out.println("Invalid Email: " + s.getEmailAddress());

    }

}
```

Comment: It should be pretty obvious that none of your email address looks like *foo@.com* with a `@.` right next to each other so you will have to split your tests for `@`and `.`

Comment: write down your logic on paper first

Comment: And don't try to guess what contains does. Read the javadoc, carefully. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains-java.lang.CharSequence-

Answer (score -1):

[contains](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains-java.lang.CharSequence-)
check for a String, here your code will return `true` only if the email adress contains `"@."` as a String. Try using
[indexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-)
:

```
String email = s.getEmailAddress();

int atIndex = email.indexOf('@');

if (atIndex < 0 || email.indexOf('.', atIndex) < 0 || email.indexOf(' ') >= 0)
    System.out.println("Invalid Email: " + email);
```

I assumed that the `.` must be found in the "right part" of the adress, after the `@`. Otherwise, you don't need `atIndex` and you can use `email.indexOf('.')` instead.

You have other ways to check email adress.
Check out this post, it may be interesting:
[What is the best Java email address validation method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624581/what-is-the-best-java-email-address-validation-method)

Comment: do you want to teach people to use variable names like `_at_Index` ?

Comment: `if (_at_Index < 0` is an email starting with an `@` correct?

Comment: @ScaryWombat sorry for the `_at_Index` ! I wanted to make it clear that "at" means "@"

Comment: @ScaryWombat `indexOf` returns -1 when the caracter is not found (check out the documentation). And yes this code only check this specification : "address contains a @ and a . after the @"

Comment: Yes, I agree that if it is returns `-1` it is an error, but what about if the value is `0` ?

Comment: I forgot to check if there is no spaces...

Comment: with your code, does this pass ? `@User9123.gmail.com`

Comment: @ScaryWombat `I have to verify that all emails have '@' and '.' and don't have a space.` is the specification I implemented. In fact I even didn't had to use `atIndex`.