# apache common validator returns false positive result

Tags: java, apache-commons, email-validation

While using Apache common Email validator as below link:

> https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/EmailValidator.html

it returns false positive result for email formatted as :

```
random@.com -> true
random.bla@gmail -> true
```

is there a better way to validate emails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you made a mistake somewhere in your code, I tested the EmailValidator and it worked, both examples returned false:

```
import org.apache.commons.validator.routines.EmailValidator;

public class TestMail {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    EmailValidator v = EmailValidator.getInstance();

    System.out.println(v.isValid("random@.com")); //false
    System.out.println(v.isValid("random.bla@gmail")); //false
}
}
```

Using the dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Looks like the current version is 1.6. 1.4.0 was release in January '12.

Answer (score 1):

For "static validation", only **the newest commons-validator version can help/improve**.

see: [What is the best Java email address validation method?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/624581/592355)

---

If you *really* want to validate an email - Of course you need to get it confirmed:

- first do static validation (as good as you/your lib can)
- then send an email:

  - with an identifying confirmation link, which recipient has to "click" (http get!).
- write the according endpoint/servlet/controller (http get), which "completes validation".

see also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-loop_authentication
...

---

Comment: This answer is extremely hard to actually read. I mean it's right, but it took like four read-throughs to figure that out.

Comment: ty, @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas, sry, it is a "wide field" :) ..and english not my native language :)

Comment: ..edited! (more structure, less parenthesis + refs ;)

Answer (score 0):

Apache common email validator valid when email address has & char but it is not true.

```
        assertFalse(EmailValidatorUtil.isValid("asdfasd&@hotmail.com"));
```