# Email validation Method creation

Tags: java, validation, email, methods

The method  returns true if such    character
is  a   letter  of  the English alphabet    (uppercase  or  lower   case)   or  one of  the arabic  numerals.   The method
returns false otherwise

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best Java email address validation method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624581/what-is-the-best-java-email-address-validation-method)

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko Afaik `:;` is a valid email address. What op mean is a mail*box*-address I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Method for ASCII character set

```
boolean isEnglishLetterOrDigit(char letter) {
      return (letter >= 'a' && letter <= 'z') ||
             (letter >= 'A' && letter <= 'Z') ||
             (letter >= '0' && letter <= '9');
  }
```